# Actionscript 2.0: inputting number, add 1 to it, output number

Tags: actionscript-2

I'm using Actionscript 2.0 because I just need very quick little bits of code to insert into SmartBoard activities. I'm trying to do something soooooooo simple, and I can't believe there isn't a simple solution to it!

Basically I want to have a teacher input a number into a textfield, press a button, have some operation done on the number, then have the answer appear in an output box. Here's the code I cobbled together:

```
on (release) {
inputnumber.restrict = "0-9";
var numberout:Number = inputnumber;
outputnumber = numberout + 1

}
```

That is all! I can't believe something this easy is so hard.

Comment: Where have you attached this code? on a button?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `restriction` a lot earlier. Its there to only allow numbers being written in the TextField, but you assign this when the button is pressed **after** the text/number was entered. Instead, put that code f.ex. on the keyframe.

For your actual problem. I can only guess what inputnumber or outputnumber is. 
**If** these are TextFields, you need to access the text that was entered into them with the text property:

```
  on (release) {
    var numberout:Number = parseInt(_root.inputnumber.text);
    _root.outputnumber.text = numberout + 1;    
}
```

Note that `parseInt` converts the `String` (text) coming from the TextField into an integer so that you can do computations like `+1` with it. If your variables are the variable names you can assign to a TextField in the properties windows, just take out the `.text`

Also note that both ways, the names are not defined *in* the code for the button. So you need to add the `_root` to tell flash you are accessing stuff outside the button and on the main stage.